# Extracting Text Between Brackets with Regex

Tags: regex, excel, vba

In sentences like:

"[x] Alpha

[33] Beta"

I extract an array of bracketed data as ([x], [33])

using VBA regex Pattern:

```
"(\[x\])|(\[\d*\])"
```

I cannot extract directly the array of un-bracketed data as (x, 33)

using web resources advice for pattern

```
"(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])"
```

Is this a VBA specific problem (i.e. limits on its implementation of Regex)
or did I misunderstand 'looking forward and backward' patterns?

```
Public Function Regx( _
  ByVal SourceString As String, _
  ByVal Pattern As String, _
  Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, _
  Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = True, _
  Optional ByVal MatchGlobal As Boolean = True) _
  As Variant

Dim oMatch As Match
Dim arrMatches
Dim lngCount As Long

' Initialize to an empty array
arrMatches = Array()
With New RegExp
    .MultiLine = MultiLine
    .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    .Global = MatchGlobal
    .Pattern = Pattern
    For Each oMatch In .Execute(SourceString)
        ReDim Preserve arrMatches(lngCount)
        arrMatches(lngCount) = oMatch.Value
        lngCount = lngCount + 1
    Next
End With


Sub testabove()
    Call Regx("[x] Alpha" & Chr(13) & _
      "[33] Beta", "(\[x\])|(\[\d*\])")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, please share the full (only relevant) code snippet for us to repro and see where you have missed something.

Comment: I presume you are using VBScript regex. Am I right?

Comment: Yes true, I added the reference to it

Comment: Here are some useful resources: [VBScript’s Regular Expression Support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html), [Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx). You can test regex patterns online here: [VBScript RegExp Example: Regular Expression Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use capturing around the subpatterns that will fetch you your required value.

Use

```
"\[(x)\]|\[(\d*)\]"
```

(or `\d+` if you need to match at least 1 digit, as `*` means *zero or more occurrences*, and `+` means *one or more occurrences*).

Or, use the **generic pattern to extract *anything* inside the square brackets without the brackets**:

```
"\[([^\][]+)]"
```

Then, access the right `Submatches` index by checking the submatch length (since you have an alternation, either of the submatch will be empty), and there you go. Just change your `for` loop with

```
For Each oMatch In .Execute(SourceString)
    ReDim Preserve arrMatches(lngCount)
    If Len(oMatch.SubMatches(0)) > 0 Then
        arrMatches(lngCount) = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
    Else
        arrMatches(lngCount) = oMatch.SubMatches(1)
    End If
    ' Debug.Print arrMatches(lngCount) ' - This outputs x and 33 with your data
    lngCount = lngCount + 1
Next
```

Comment: Dear Wiktor, I will upvote all the people that made a help, this is a duty of mine. However, please note that as I am still low on points, this will not show until my points go higher.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\[(x)\]|\[(\d*)\]
```

What you don't want to be captured, don't put them inside (). this is used for grouping

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DffZNA/2)

```
You will get x and 33 in $1 and $2
```

[Dot Net Sample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28x%29%5C%5D%7C%5C%5B%28%5Cd*%29%5C%5D&i=%22%5Bx%5D%20Alpha%0D%0A%0D%0A%5B33%5D%20Beta%5D%22)

Alright, I prepared it for you , although far away from vb for long. Lots of it might be not needed, yet it might help you to understand it better

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      Dim text As String = "[x] Alpha      [33] Beta]"
      Dim pattern As String = "\[(x)\]|\[(\d*)\]"

      ' Instantiate the regular expression object.
      Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

      ' Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
      Dim m As Match = r.Match(text)
      Dim matchcount as Integer = 0
      Do While m.Success
         matchCount += 1
         Console.WriteLine("Match" & (matchCount))
         Dim i As Integer
         For i = 1 to 2
            Dim g as Group = m.Groups(i)
            Console.WriteLine("Group" & i & "='" & g.ToString() & "'")
            Dim cc As CaptureCollection = g.Captures
            Dim j As Integer 
            For j = 0 to cc.Count - 1
              Dim c As Capture = cc(j)
               Console.WriteLine("Capture" & j & "='" & c.ToString() _
                  & "', Position=" & c.Index)
            Next 
         Next 
         m = m.NextMatch()
      Loop
   End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: My code still returns [x] and [33]... Is it that I am now properly extracting $1 and $2? I will edit my post to include the code then

Comment: In the dot net sample link, you can look into the table at the bottom. which consists the break down of the match...

Comment: Yes I got what you are trying to say, still how to get programmatic-ally in an array the required unbracketed list?

Answer (score 1):

With Excel and VBA you can strip the brackets **after** the regex extraction:

```
Sub qwerty()

    Dim inpt As String, outpt As String
    Dim MColl As MatchCollection, temp2 As String
    Dim regex As RegExp, L As Long

    inpt = "38c6v5hrk[x]537fhvvb"

    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "(\[x\])|(\[\d*\])"
    Set MColl = regex.Execute(inpt)
    temp2 = MColl(0).Value

    L = Len(temp2) - 2
    outpt = Mid(temp2, 2, L)

    MsgBox inpt & vbCrLf & outpt
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Gary's Student: can you extract all unbrackated values into one array?

Answer (score 1):

Array Without Regex:

```
For Each Value In Split(SourceString, Chr(13))
  ReDim Preserve arrMatches(lngCount)
  arrMatches(lngCount) = Split(Split(Value, "]")(0), "[")(1)
  lngCount = lngCount + 1
Next
```